# How to prevent page scrolling with tinymce

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, tinymce

I have a tinyMCE editor with the editing toolbar set to being external. The positioning for this is "fixed". The problem is that every time a user clicks on anything in the toolbar (while changing text font, etc), the whole page jumps to so that the toolbar is at the top of the page. How can I not allow the browser page to jump like this?

Can I somehow add in the default handlers of tinymce something that will prevent this?

Comment: Can you please post your code (or) give us a fiddle to check?

Comment: have the same issue here, but with firefox though